# Instagram Graph Api Content Publishing Works Perfectly on Graph API Explorer But Malfunctions on Browser And Other HTTP Request including Curl

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media?image_url=https://www.example.com/images/bronz-fonz.jpg&caption=he&access_token={Myaccess Token}
```

(Replaced My real Page ID and image url to generic ones for security reasons)
When I call the above URL using Graph API Explorer, it works perfectly as it should.

By Working Well I Mean...

I'm able to get a container ID with which I'm able to publish image to my instagram accounts. I have actually successfully published images with caption to two of my Instagram accounts connected to my facebook pages.

But when I try making the same API call from php using curl or file_get_contents() it returns empty JSON data for one of my IG accounts and returns multiple ids on another account at the same time.

And when I try any of the returned multiple ids for publishing my image it comes back with a bad request error.
Below Is The My Code:

```
  //Make An Image Post Request To Get IG Container IG       //1)file_get_contents()option
`$instagram_publish_call=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$mypage_id}/media?image_url={$myimage_url}&caption={$mymessage}&access_token={$myaccess_token}");
    instagram_url="https://graph.facebook.com/{$mypage_id}/media?image_url={$myimage_url}&caption={$mymessage}&access_token={$myaccess_token}";
//2)PHP curl option
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $instagram_url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $contents=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
  echo $contents;
```

At first, I thought it had to do with my script or the PHP functions I was using, so I decided to make the calls directly on my browsers by just copying and pasting the url, including my long live access token and surprisingly it still returns the same result as it does in my php code.  That is, one of the accounts returning empty JSON and the other returning multiple ids  that are not useful on the browser.

Here is the erroneous results from the different IG accounts...

1. Response From One of my IG Accounts

   {
   "data": [
   {
   "id": "23445667778889990000"
   },
   {
   "id": "233456788989999999"
   },
   {
   "id": "22344566777788888"
   },
   {
   "id": "123445667788899000"
   },
   {
   "id": "1234456677889999"
   },
   {
   "id": "123346889999000"
   },
   {
   "id": "1234567789999000"
   },
   {
   "id": "123456789900---"
   },
   {
   "id": "12334567789090"
   },
   {
   "id": "122334456778899900"
   },
   {
   "id": "45567889990000000"
   }
   ],
   "paging": {
   "cursors": {
   "before": "ADSGNFNFMGKGMKGKGKGKGKKG",
   "after": "QWREFDGHHJUKUKLK;L;LLL;LLLL"
   }
   }
   }

(I replaced actual IDs and response codes for security reasons)
2)Response from second account...

{
"data": [

]
}

My Desired Response Which I Actually Get From Facebook Graph Explorer is..

{
"id":1784999847888888888
}

Please can Anyone help me, because this has taken so much of my time.

Comment: If I had to guess (which we _don't_ want to have to do here, so please go read [ask] and [mre], before you ask your next question here!) - then I'd say you probably made GET instead of POST requests ...?

Comment: CBroe Following your answer I added this line curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true); to my CURL request and it seems you were actually right. But now it returns "Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can." I have tried many times and still am getting same error. I have tried both Chrome and Explorer, with the same result.

Comment: The browser is of rather little relevance, when we are talking about stuff happening on the server side here. // Graph API Explorer has a button to generate code for your request, you can at least get cURL command line code from there. (And there's tools available on the net, to translate that to PHP cURL code.)

Comment: CBroe, thanks for your help thus far. As per your direction, I ran the code again with graph explorer and got the desired output, which is json data with a single IG container Id, Then at the bottom of the graph explorer, I was able to copy the cURL command , then I converted it to PHP cURL code. I have also used the php code in my app and it still returns the same error message from facebook. Can you still suggest any other thing I can do to remedy the situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you execute the cURL command directly via CLI?

Comment: I just executed the cURL command directly via CLI using my command prompt and it returns the same error as I am having using the PHP curl version. I mean this same error   "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can. "

Comment: Are you sure you are actually making a POST request? At least the PHP code you have shown above, appears to be making a GET.

Comment: I have edited my code to prove that I am actually making a POST request. But all the same I believe you have tried your best to help. At least the first error I was receiving has been resolved due to your suggestion that I was making a GET request instead of POST request. I will continue looking for solution to the new Facebook error.

Comment: The cURL code the tools suggests, does not appear to be sending any actual POST parameters, the values are still contained as GET parameters in the URL. I'd just write it myself here, a basic POST request using cURL in PHP isn't too hard.

Comment: CBroe If you can help me with the cURL in PHP that you believe will fix the issue I'll be most grateful